# from keras.layers import Dense -- cannot import name 'Dense'

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to play around with Keras a little.

When I try the following code :

```
from keras.layers import Dense
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.layers import Dense
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dense'
```

I am using Python 3.4.3, I am on a Windows 8 64 bit machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error is telling you that it found nothing named `Dense` in that module.

Perhaps you meant `from keras.layers.core import Dense`?

Comment: Worked Perfectly. I, however, have a small query. How did you know that this was the solution? I mean, what was your problem-solving methodology?

Comment: I googled "python keras layers dense", went to the top search result page, saw there was an object named Dense on that page, and noted that the full module name of that object was `keras.layers.core.Dense`.

Answer (score 0):

`from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation`

when trying to import above line i was facing error. The answer would be

`from keras.layers import Dense, Activation` as core module do not contain Activation.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: For me, from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense solved the issue.